# How to mount a root aufs in Red Hat / Fedora Core?

Tags: linux, init, rootfs, unionfs

I'm trying to set up a virtual machine running Red Hat EL (actually Scientific Linux, but same difference) where the root file system is protected and not writable. I'd like to accomplish this with a union mount using [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/). That is, a writable file system (on a different virtual HDD) is overlayed on the root file system.

Is there a HOWTO on this anywhere? I have the aufs module installed, and I've been able to mount a union file system, but the trick is to do this for the root file system.

I've seen initramfs scripts help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash written for Debian/Ubuntu-style distributions that do this sort of thing inside the /init script: Before the real root is mounted, the protected root is mounted somewhere as read-only, the overlayed file system is mounted elsewhere as read-write, the union file system is created and mounted, and then the union mount becomes the real root. Hence, the original protected root file system is never mounted as read-write.

I'd like to know how to do this in the nash /init script of Red Hat distributions.

*Even more specific questions:* What exactly do the nash commands "setuproot" and "switchroot" do? The man page for nash(8) documents switchroot with a single argument, but my /init script calls it without any arguments.

(Motivation: the virtual machine will be subjected to software fault injection; I want to protect the root file system from the effects of a faulty system so that I can quickly reboot the VM into a non-faulty state.)

Thanks!!

*P.S. Yes, I could just download some LiveCD and see how it's done there, but I thought somebody should have written a HOWTO that my Googling skills have not discovered.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initrd contains a gzipped cpio dump that's put onto a ramdisk during init.  Setuproot loads any necessary modules (contained in the initrd), generally for things like LVM, populates /dev (the initrd contains a limited /dev).  Switchroot pivots off the cpio archive to the real root filesystem.

nash is *extremely* limited.  Every binary must be static, scripting is virtually impossible, etc.  [This](http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/build.html) may be helpful (build scripts are in his SVN repo).

Comment: Ok, so basically, LiveCD's and other distributions that need fancy stuff done inside initrd use a more capable shell such as ash or bash.

Comment: Busybox is very common as an inclusion just to yank ash, yes.  ash and dash are preferred.  You can yank [this](http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/download/build/livecd-3.0.2.tar.gz).  Check in `/livecd-3.0.2/linux-live.sl/initrd` and you'll find a linuxrc that does almost exactly what you want.